# How to get an String and the ArrayList stored in a Arraylist of objects of a class using Java stream

Tags: java, arraylist, iteration, java-stream, getter-setter

I have modified the code and trying to get an ArrayList and the String stored in an Arraylist of Objects on a specific condition(say 'str' string equal to 2). I'm not able to convert the Stream to ArrayList. Please help me understand what needs to be done to get the ArrayList from this stream.

I have a class 'SampleClass' like below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SampleClass {
String str;
ArrayList<String> al;
String check;

public SampleClass(String str, ArrayList<String> al, String check) {
    super();
    this.str = str;
    this.al = al;
    this.check = check;
}
public String getStr() {
    return str;
}
public void setStr(String str) {
    this.str = str;
}
public ArrayList<String> getAl() {
    return al;
}
public void setAl(ArrayList<String> al) {
    this.al = al;
}
public String getCheck() {
    return check;
}
public void setCheck(String check) {
    this.check = check;
}

}
```

I have another class 'GetTheArrayListStoredInAnotherArrayList' like below where I'm trying to get the ArrayList stored inside the ArrayList of objects. Please correct me where I'm wrong.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class GetTheArrayListStoredInAnotherArrayList{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "qw,rer,try,try,erh5,wertgw45t,45";
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    al.addAll(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(test.split(","))));
    System.out.println(al);
    ArrayList<SampleClass> sca = new ArrayList<SampleClass>();
    SampleClass sc1 = new SampleClass("1", al,"ch1");
    SampleClass sc2 = new SampleClass("2", al,"cc2");
    SampleClass sc3 = new SampleClass("3", al,"fr3");
    SampleClass sc4 = new SampleClass("4", al,"fg4");
    sca.add(sc1);
    sca.add(sc2);
    sca.add(sc3);
    sca.add(sc4);
    ArrayList<String> als1 = null;
    ArrayList<String> als = sca.stream().filter( s -> s.getStr().equals("2")).flatMap(sc -> sc.getAl().stream()).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    System.out.println(als);
    String ch = (String) sca.stream().filter(s -> s.getStr().equals("1")).map(ac -> ac.getCheck());
    System.out.println(ch);
}
}
```

I got the below error when I executed the code :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Cannot cast from Stream<String> to String

at GetTheArrayListStoredInAnotherArrayList.main(GetTheArrayListStoredInAnotherArrayList.java:24)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but you need to change your code a bit:

```
         List<String> als = sca.stream()
             .filter(s -> s.getStr().equals("2"))
             .flatMap(sc -> sc.getAl().stream())
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

A few things :

`flatMap` must return a `Stream` (in your case you are returning a `List`)

`Collectors.toList` makes no guarantee of the `List` in returns, so the assignment is to a `List`, not an `ArrayList`.

**EDIT**

This:

```
  Stream<String> stream = sca.stream().filter(s -> s.getStr().equals("1"))
                                   .map(ac -> ac.getCheck());
```

Will produce a `Stream<String>`. You can't simply cast that to a `String`, you have to collect/reduce that to whatever you want. Like let's say a `List`:

```
  List<String> list = sca.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.getStr().equals("1"))
        .map(ac -> ac.getCheck())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or a single `String` for example:

```
  String r = sca.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.getStr().equals("1"))
        .map(ac -> ac.getCheck())
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

This is actually basic stuff... you should *really* study some samples and the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me a lot. I ysed the line

Comment: You can use `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)` if you need to return `ArrayList` specifically.

Comment: I have used the below line of code to acheive what I wanted now.
ArrayList<String> als = sca.stream().filter( s -> s.getStr().equals("2")).flatMap(sc -> sc.getAl().stream()).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

Comment: Thanks for the Answers. Your answers helped me to achieve my target. I have one more doubt regarding how to cast from Stream<String> to String. I have modified the code and title accordingly. Can you please help me ?

Comment: Hi Eugene, Thanks for the answer. I used .collect(Collectors.joining(",")); to achieve what I wanted. Thanks for the timely reply.

Comment: @Eugene : I am new to stackoverflow. Can you please tell me how to accept the answer. I clicked on the tick symbol and the up arrow once. Which one is the correct one ?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
ArrayList<String> als = sca.stream().filter( s -> s.getStr().equals("2")).flatMap( sc -> sc.getAl());
```

To

```
ArrayList<String> als = sca.get(0).getAl();
```

Comment: You can probably do .stream() after get(0). Not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to use List instead of ArrayList. So with List you code will looks like

```
List<String> als1 = null;
    List<String> als = sca.stream().
            filter(s -> s.getStr().equals("2")).  //Comparing 
            map(s -> s.getAl())  // Converting List<SampleClass> to list of all al list inside all SampleClass in format List<List<Straing>> 
            .flatMap(ArrayList::stream)  //Creating a flat list from list of list of List ::  List<List<Straing>> --To--> List<String>
            .collect(Collectors.toList());  // Collecting as list
```

I have commented this code with details. But here if there are two SampleCalss objects in the list with **str=2** then it will merge the **al** list of both objects. hope it will help you .

Comment: Thanks Satish. Your answer helped me to achieve my target. I have one more doubt regarding how to cast from Stream<String> to String. Can you please help me ?

Comment: Can you please give me some more information about your query , Like what you want to do . What i can under from your one line query is you want to convert collection or array <String> to ->  Stream<String> -to-> "a single concatenated string" ? Please explain your question a little more.

Comment: I have a ArrayList of objects a class (SampleClass which has three class variables {2 strings - str and check and a AraayList al}) and I need to iterate through this ArrayList and get the value of the String check when the value of the string str is equal to "1" using java streams. Please refer to the code changes in the question. Hope I explained clearly.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to get the ArrayList stored inside the ArrayList of objects.

Well, the basic algorithm is as follows: Filter `sca` so it only leaves elements where `str` is "2" -> Get a single element from all the left over elements -> Get the `al` stored inside of that element.

You have done the first part correctly:

```
sca.stream().filter( s -> s.getStr().equals("2"))
```

But now you need to get a single element from the filtered result (filter can result in multiple elements being left over), so you call `findFirst`:

```
.findFirst().get()
```

This `get` call will throw an exception if there is no element left after the filter. If you don't want it to throw an exception, you can replace it with an `orElse` call:

```
.findFirst.orElse(new SampleClass("", null))
```

If you use `orElse`, the method chain will evaluate to `null` if no element with `str` being "2".

Now you just need to get the array list by calling `getAl()`:

```
.getAl();
```

Now we combine all this together:

```
ArrayList<String> als = sca.stream()
    .filter( s -> s.getStr().equals("2"))
    .findFirst().orElse(new SampleClass("", null)).getAl();
```